# How to add a blank line under a header

Tags: support, status-completed, markdown

### [TagSoup](http://mercury.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/)

They claim

> The general view around the Web seems to be that TagSoup is the slowest, but also the most robust and reliable.

---

How do I add a blank line under the header to keep the "they claim" part from dissappearing?
 (I actually *also* want to remove the blank line *under* "they claim")

```
[TagSoup](http://mercury.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/)
-
They claim
>The general view around the Web seems to be that TagSoup is the slowest, but also the most robust and reliable.
```

Comment: Inserting two `<br>`s works. On a general note, we have a  [formatting sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) where you can try things out.

Comment: @Reg Actually, a single <br> would be enough if it's placed on a line between the header and the upcoming text. Works whether you use the hyphen syntax or the pound syntax.

Comment: I should't comment, as I sometimes even abuse `<sub>` for footnotes. But still: I think that the formatting should be done by the web site. Indeed, a header could use some whitespace below it, but if the website (currently) doesn't do that, we shouldn't add it ourselves. Note that content might be rendered in different views (website, print stylesheet, RSS/Atom, maybe mobile?) and might also be used on non-Stack Overflow applications and sites (http://stackapps.com/, api, datadump).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I agree -- I'll have Jin define styles for post bodies that put a bit of whitespace under `<h3> <h2> <h1>` headers and the like.

Ah, this is now implemented:

> #### Header 3
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce vulputate tempor lacus ac dignissim. Ut volutpat tincidunt dui, sit amet tristique arcu pulvinar sed. Fusce fermentum magna quis tellus adipiscing aliquam. Duis id turpis sit amet diam tempor sollicitudin. Maecenas gravida ultricies augue. Aliquam augue est, scelerisque ut eleifend sed, ullamcorper non arcu. Fusce at augue id enim sagittis rutrum vitae ac ante. Donec velit lorem, semper at feugiat sed, sodales a felis. Fusce sagittis leo vel diam egestas posuere. Mauris pretium, metus ut consequat imperdiet, turpis mi tristique eros, elementum condimentum lectus odio auctor ipsum. Fusce ut euismod sem. Aenean aliquam bibendum risus, semper pretium quam pharetra quis.
>
> ### Header 2
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce vulputate tempor lacus ac dignissim. Ut volutpat tincidunt dui, sit amet tristique arcu pulvinar sed. Fusce fermentum magna quis tellus adipiscing aliquam. Duis id turpis sit amet diam tempor sollicitudin. Maecenas gravida ultricies augue. Aliquam augue est, scelerisque ut eleifend sed, ullamcorper non arcu. Fusce at augue id enim sagittis rutrum vitae ac ante. Donec velit lorem, semper at feugiat sed, sodales a felis. Fusce sagittis leo vel diam egestas posuere. Mauris pretium, metus ut consequat imperdiet, turpis mi tristique eros, elementum condimentum lectus odio auctor ipsum. Fusce ut euismod sem. Aenean aliquam bibendum risus, semper pretium quam pharetra quis.
>
> ## Header 1
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce vulputate tempor lacus ac dignissim. Ut volutpat tincidunt dui, sit amet tristique arcu pulvinar sed. Fusce fermentum magna quis tellus adipiscing aliquam. Duis id turpis sit amet diam tempor sollicitudin. Maecenas gravida ultricies augue. Aliquam augue est, scelerisque ut eleifend sed, ullamcorper non arcu. Fusce at augue id enim sagittis rutrum vitae ac ante. Donec velit lorem, semper at feugiat sed, sodales a felis. Fusce sagittis leo vel diam egestas posuere. Mauris pretium, metus ut consequat imperdiet, turpis mi tristique eros, elementum condimentum lectus odio auctor ipsum. Fusce ut euismod sem. Aenean aliquam bibendum risus, semper pretium quam pharetra quis.

Comment: Not meaning to look a gift horse in the mouth, but: what about some whitespace *above* the headers too...? Especially H1 seems a bit unbalanced to me [right now](http://i.imgur.com/gmsN2.png).

Comment: This is no bueno. It's that classic... is this figcaption for the image above... ?
 - or below... ?    see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82281/can-we-balance-the-whitespace-above-below-headings/299652#299652 - for proposed CSS solution.