# Add space above the header too

Tags: feature-request, design, markdown, header

See Arjan's comment on this answer on my question: [How to add a blank line under a header](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72922/how-to-add-a-blank-line-under-a-header/74489#74489)

It was not my idea to globally add space under the header... but we should certainly make the top space at least as much as the bottom space no matter what global setting we use.