# Can we balance the whitespace above/below headings?

Tags: feature-request, design

In January, some additional whitespace [was added](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72922/how-to-add-a-blank-line-under-a-header/74489#74489) below h1, h2 and h3 headings, [yielding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmsN2.png) more whitespace below the headers than above them.

Could we have the whitespace above the headings be more than the whitespace below them?

I find some posts *a bit* hard to read, like the current rendering on the left:

[image: Unbalanced whitespace in headings]       [image: Unbalanced whitespace in headings]

Comment: I find myself including a `<br />` before headings. This looks great... but I'll wish they weren't there if this is ever addressed. I'm not sure how 'Answers' work in `meta` - but I can offer my suggestion in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that placing margins *above* elements helps me maintain markup and markdown styles. I usually keep a kitchen-sink of markup in an `<article>` to style and ensure all cases are accounted for.

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/v3kjL8ae/

If we had something like this in place

### People like me wouldn't fee compelled to add `<br /`> above

headings like this

### heading level 2

paragraph

### heading level 2

paragraph

VS...

### heading level 2

paragraph

### heading level 2

paragraph

```css
article {
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
}

p {
  font-size: 16px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: red;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: blue;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) { 
  /* hopefully you use stylus or something for smooth mixins */
  h1 { /* just one example */
    font-size: 26px;
  }
}

p:not(:first-of-type) {
  margin-top: .5rem;
}

h1 + p { /* any p elements that follow an h1 */
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

p + h2 {
  margin-top: 2rem; /* a $pad variable would be best */
}
```

```html
<article>

  <h1>heading level 1 (is likely the question, right)</h1>
  
  <p>I usually start out my answer with an overview of why I'm going to say what I'm going to say.</p>
  
  <p>As far as web-specific stuff, I'll then likely write sections for 'markup' 'styles' and 'functionality' or something like that</p>
  
  <h2>Heading level 2 for 'markup'</h2>
  
  <p>I wont put a codeblock here, but a paragraph under a heading should be good enough for the example.</p>
  
  <p>Subsequent paragraphs.</p> 
  
  <h2>Heading level 2 for 'something else'</h2>
  
  <p>I wont put a codeblock here, but a paragraph under a heading should be good enough for the example.</p>  

</article>
```

This mindset can really take care of business. I'd be happy to go into it further.