# Subdue the font size for headings

Tags: feature-request, design, markdown

Font sizes for headings across all Stack Exchange sites is garish and significantly overstated, giving an amateurish look to questions that use headings where they would otherwise be quite appropriate.

For example [this answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/518/how-can-i-be-sure-someone-i-know-is-going-to-heaven/524#524) uses quite semantically appropriate h2 tags (via ##) and yet it presents horribly.  I know I have tried using h1 and h2 before and just switch to bold or bold+underline for this very reason.

Can h1 and h2 ***within*** question and answer text be mapped to be just bold plus a slight increase in size over the base text size, say 2 points and 1 point respectively, and perhaps h3 to bold+underline.

And, secondarily, perhaps the remaining heading values should be do-nothing (and reserved for future use).

Comment: I happen to agree with this. `<H2>` is horribly abused on Programmers.SE to get undue attention for answers, and it would be nice to know why the community disagrees with a modest font size decrease.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## YES

...there is no reason I can see (apart from drawing attention) to have such big headings in concise answers. Unless, of course, a question / answer needs to be structured in several articles, paragraphs on dozens of pages with an overall index.

### Besides...

I happen to feel ashamed too, to use headings, because I feel like I'm drawing too much attention...

Answer (score 3):

Also, please decrease the spacing below a header. Make the header be part of the section it's the heading for, not something in between two sections:

[image]

Comment: Oh, I apparently forgot I already asked for this 2 years earlier, now 3 years ago: [Can we balance the whitespace above/below headings?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82281/can-we-balance-the-whitespace-above-below-headings) (Some day I'll give in and add annoying manual line breaks...)