# Heading h2 changes to make it stand out a little less

Tags: discussion, design

I feel that the h2-headings with their CSS properties make them stand out a little bit too much in questions and answers. Many users seem to prefer using bold text for headings – possibly because the current h2-headings look too big. Could something be done to make it feel more acceptable to layout the structure of a post using headings instead of bolded text headings?

There's also a bit more [specific discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104240/230612) going into the subject of heading sizes.

### Possible solutions

I played around with the `margin-bottom` property, and a value of `0.5em` somehow looked more right from my point of view – at least on my own questions and answers, which try to conform heavily on the semantically correct use of heading tags.

Comment: So use h3 instead?

Comment: Your "possible solutions" seems to make this a duplicate of this: [Can we balance the whitespace above/below headings?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82281) (which I strongly support).