# Please improve the font used for Markdown-rendered headers on Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, design, user-interface, markdown-rendering

This question is about the *Stack Exchange* sites' implementation of the Markdown semantics. I apologize for its ugliness, but it does serve to underline my point.

It is often painful to read posts that use the `#` markdown device to indicate a header. Something like

```
# Header 1

## Header 2

### Header 3
```

produces

## Header 1

### Header 2

#### Header 3

This is in keeping with the the Markdown specification, but unless the author has experience with web coding they are unlikely to know that, with headers, more means less. It regularly results in ugly and awkward posts with over-sized bold fonts mixed in.

This is different from the very similar emphasis stars, where

```
*Emphasis 1*

**Emphasis 2**

***Emphasis 3***
```

gives

*Emphasis 1*

**Emphasis 2**

***Emphasis 3***

---

#### I propose that

The stylesheet should render `<h1>`, `<h2>` and `<h3>` in a more appropriate font - serifed, with balanced leading and a less overwheming point size

Comment: #3 is not a bug - [it's part of the Markdown spec](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#header).

Comment: On a somewhat related note; I always find myself wanting something between header 2 and 3

Comment: @Richard `##.5 me too`

Comment: @michaelb958: Ah I see, thanks. So one or more hyphens serve to underline the previous line. Then I guess I have a problem with markdown, as a `<hr>` requires three or more hyphens: I think an underline should behave similarly.

Comment: @RichardTingle: Somehow I always need my editor's font set to 11pt

Comment: @Borodin I don't follow you entirely. You raise the issue that _more hashes_ means _less emphasized header_, and contrast it with emphasis stars, where _more stars_ means _more emphasis_. That's an ok point to raise. But then you assert it leads to super-bolded posts, which isn't an assertion you've actually demonstrated to be true. And then your suggestion is to change the font for headings, which appears to be nothing to do with either part of the problem you raised.

Comment: Also: I think the over-bolded posts you're noticing are not because of headings; it's because some people don't understand that for emphasis to work, you need to have only a little bit of it.

Comment: In fact, if I had my way, the body text would be serif, probably Bookman, the code in the wonderful Source Code Pro, and the headers in Avant Garde. I'm off to Greasemonkey exactly that.

Comment: Me want serif. Me want smaller. And me want h3 bigger.

Comment: @bjb568: On the grounds that `<h2>` should look different from `<strong>` I kinda agree. But serifs, yes please.

Comment: With millions of posts already using it, we're not gonna make arbitrary changes to the Markdown spec we implement - so #3 is out. Don't know what considerations need to be given to the font used for headers, but it is at least within the broad range of *theoretical possibility.*

Comment: @Borodin Should we remove #3 from this post? The header styles are still something worth dealing with.

Comment: I'm more annoyed by the spacing above and below the headers, but that has not changed for 3 years: [Can we balance the whitespace above/below headings?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82281/can-we-balance-the-whitespace-above-below-headings)... Also related: [Subdue the font size for headings](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104240/subdue-the-font-size-for-headings).

Comment: @Shog9: I am more than happy to retract #3 now that I understand it is part of the markdown spec. I wouldn't expect SO to offer any variations from that. Outside the meta site I would discourage modification of the original question as it makes nonsense of preceding comments and answers. What should I do here? And what happens next? It looks like there are people who entusiastically agree with me, but do I just leave the authorities to cherry pick which changes they will make?

Comment: I already edited this to focus on the font; I would just drop #3 if I was you.

Comment: @Shog9: Done. So now many people like the idea, it has been upvoted, but it will sink beneath younger posts. What must happen to get a request approved?

Comment: Jin (our head designer) has some plans for cleaning up the styling on SO eventually - if he decides it makes sense, it'll happen then.